# Winforms Cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` I want to change it's cursor so am doing the following

```
picBox.Cursor = new Cursor(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\crop1.cur");
```

it throws this exception :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Image format is not valid. The image file may be corrupted.
```

the file am using : 
[The Cursor.cur](https://www.mediafire.com/?u2gufzeibzwi9u7)

without using P/Invoke ....

Comment: It is a "fancy" cursor, created from a PNG file.  They can only be used on later versions of Windows, .NET support for cursors got stuck at XP.  You can use the code in the dup question to load it.

Comment: this is not a duplicated question , I don't want to use P/Invoking...

Comment: Then you must redesign the cursor.